# Flexbox align-items:center not perfect in the center

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm having trouble with the flexbox tool `align-items:center;` is not perfect in the middle but a few pixels too high on the text, icons,... Someone knows how to solve this?

[screenshot how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQEGS.png)

For example, this is the html/css code I use for the post item.

```css
.post-item {
  background-color: white;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 30px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<tbody>
  <tr class="post-item">
    <td class="post-title">
      <a href="#">Hier komt de titelddd</a>
    </td>
    <td class="post-author">
      <div>Chickmeister69</div>
    </td>
    <td class="post-date">
      <div>18/09/17 - 00:33</div>
    </td>
    <td class="post-go">
      <img src="assets/go_forward_arrow.svg" alt="go">
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: can you put a complete code with HTML so we can tests ?

Comment: please put the HTML code.

Comment: Consider checking `line-height` on `inline` elements as well.

Comment: If you want  a proper answer you need to provide a working code snippet reproducing the issue. Also, I strongly recommend to not turn `table` elements into Flexbox, as `table` being a very old, inconsistent cross browsers and Flexbox the newest tech, you will most likely run into cross browser issues

Comment: Furthermore, align _text_ in the exact vertical middle will be almost impossible, as font families internal metrics differs, and also how browsers and operating systems handle them.

Comment: Add `.post-item img { display:block; }`

Comment: @LGSon I guess to use div's in sections is a better option than?

Comment: @KeithDemeulenaere Absolutely...and if you find yourself in need of a `table` element, use CSS Table https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display

Comment: Adding `line-height: 0;` works. See https://codepen.io/liyuanqiu/pen/orMRmq

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox align-items take margin into account, so you may want to remove `bottom-margin: 10px;` to have it perfectly vertically centered.

Comment: Removing it don't solve the problem, other suggestions?

Comment: Can you create this example completely in JSFiddle or Codepen so we don't have to ask multiple subquestions?